# Convert curl command to python get request

Tags: python, curl

I have subscribed to an API which gave me an authorization token and the following curl command:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer 37d5a9ac5442ba9f594a8ca1421a27b" "https://blah/blah/blah"
```

This curl works in terminal and returns some json when I run it. Now I need to work with the returned json so I wanted to either do this request in JS or python. Here's my python attempt:

```
url = "https://blah/blah/blah"
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authentication": "Bearer 37d5a9ac5442ba9f594a8ca1421a27b"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

This responds with:

```
{"fault":{"code":900902,"message":"Missing Credentials","description":"Required OAuth credentials not provided. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: \"Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN\""}}
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't have an explicit username and password like other answers to similar questions suggest.

Comment: Executing the curl statement resulted in a 200 OK being returned from the server?

Comment: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: @kkaosninja The curl statement prints the expected json so I'm assuming the status code is 200.

Comment: @IanD I believe sideshowbarker's answer should solve your problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says your request needs to include a header named `Authorization`.

But your Python code snippet instead has a request with the header name `Authentication`.